# Select rows from table where column value matches any item in array

Tags: postgresql

I would like to execute a case insensitive match on a column looking for any match for a given array of strings.

Example:

If a row contained values

```
id, comment
1, 'This is my comment'
```

And I was trying to match any term in the array `('statement','term','comment')`

I would love a query something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE ( string_to_array(comment, ' ')  ANY ('{term}') );
```

Now I understand the ANY function is meant to be applied to array columns but this is effectively what I would like to achieve.

What I am trying to avoid is having to iterate through all of the terms and execute an individual query for each and then have to remove duplicates etc etc.

EDIT:

So I was able to find a solution which seems to work. Although I would still love more feedback to determine if this is a reasonable approach.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE string_to_array(LOWER(column_name), ' ')::varchar[] && '{term1,term2,term3}'::varchar[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two ways to achieve this:

1. Use ANY & ARRAY of terms

> ```
> SELECT * FROM
> (SELECT 1 id , 'This is my comment' comment1
> UNION
> SELECT 2, 'Another statement') data
> WHERE comment1 ~~ ANY(ARRAY['%comment%', '%statement%'])
> ```

2. SIMILAR TO

> ```
> SELECT * FROM
> (SELECT 1 id , 'This is my comment' comment1
> UNION
> SELECT 2, 'Another statement') data
> WHERE comment1 SIMILAR TO '%(comment|statement)%'
> ```